# Socket buffer size dynamic

Tags: java, network-programming

I develop a speed test software with a graph. Each seconds, i draw the throughput on the graph. I use socket with a loop on socket.read(...)

The problem is the buffer size. If i set the buffer to 32ko, when the speed is low, my graph is wrong (block on read function until the buffer isn't full). If i set the buffer to 512 octets, the speed is "flanged".

How to set dynamically the buffer size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize recv (and send) buffers like so:

```
    int oldsize = sock.getReceiveBufferSize();
    sock.setReceiveBufferSize(oldsize * 2);
```

..although its not a great idea.  Resizing the buffer 'on the fly' like this causes at least one massive array to array data copy to happen internal to the socket, which is a massive performance loss. Additionally, sockets have an OS restriction on their max buffer size.

If you are blocking on a read() call, then I guess you are using regular IO, not NIO. I recommend using a preallocated, fixed size intermediate buffer and loop for moving data off the socket:

```
    /* Init socket here... */
    Socket sock = new Socket(...);

    /* Set time out to next to nothing. */
    sock.setSoTimeout(1);

    /* Setup Streams */
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();     

    /*  Pick a buffer size, any reasonable size will do: 1k,2k,4k... */
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 2];
    int lastRead = 0;

    do {
        try {
            lastRead = 0;
            lastRead = is.read(buf);
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
          /* Do something, or not.  Your call! */
        }

        /*do something with 'buf' here */

    } while (lastRead > 0);
```

By setting a low read timeout, e.g. 1ms, your read() call will not block (for very long) and you will still be able to detect whether there is data available or not. Since this potentially uses an Exception process a 'normal' condition, this really borders on abuse of java.io.

Comment: @claymore1977 : what is the maximum buffer size possible, generally?

Comment: Honestly, that is an OS dependent question.  I honestly don't know the 'general' answer.  Operationally, I cannot think of a legitimate reason to set a socket buffer size beyond what is default.

Comment: As far as I know, Java sockets inputStream always blocks on read() and read(byte[]). Then code above is wrong in that lastRead will never == 0; It will always be >=1 or -1 if end of stream.

The only time it will return 0 is if you give it a byte[] of zero length or ask it to read 0 bytes.

 If you want to know if there are bytes available then use available() on the socket input stream. It is also very desirable to wrap a socket inputstream with a buffered input stream. The default receive buffer is usually sufficient and is default to 8k. –

Comment: To be fair, the above code is pseudo code and will not compile.  It was for example only.  To the point though: Yes, InputStream.read() can return zero in certain situations.  The one that springs to mind immedately is if the socket has a [time out set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)).

Also, per the docs [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()] InputStream.available() is an approximation only, so its usefulness is rather limited and certainly not suited for allocating buffers.  (Per docs and experience)

Comment: There is no case where a timeout returns a zero value:
"If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid."

'if (lastRead == 0)' is never, ever, going to happen unless you use a zero length array to start with - which would be a bug IMO.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  I know there's a situation where one can make .read() return zero, but I can't find it in my notes.  I'll edit the above answer.  When I find the specifics of read() returning zero, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @claymore1977 Saint Hill has already described the only situation in which `InputStream.read()` can return zero. Your answer remains incorrect. Specifically, your statement 'your read() call will not block' is just plain wrong. -1

Comment: SaintHill: I did find my notes (finally) but just never got around to updating this answer.  The zero length buffer is indeed the only time read() could return zero. +1 to you.
EJP: My answer to FinalSpirits question of 'How to set dynamically the buffer size ?' is perfectly correct.  Simply use socket.setReceiveBufferSize().  When I made the statement of 'your read() call will not block' I failed to put the setSoTimeout call in my pseudocode, so my recommendation to FinalSpirit was incorrect. This has been fixed.

Answer (score 5):

> block on read function until the buffer isn't full

I don't know what that means. Socket reads don't attempt to fill the buffer, they wait until some data arrives and then move that into the buffer, whatever its length, up to the size of the buffer. The size of the buffer should have no effect when speeds are low. It will take effect when speeds are *high.*

Comment: I set a buffer to 32kb, and i download to 5kb/s, in debug mode java stop on read function during 3/4 seconds. I change the buffer size to 5kb, no stop on read function. Why ?

Comment: *What* read function? The only Java method I am aware of that behaves like that is DataInputStream.readFully(). To which the answer is, don't call it, call read(byte[] buffer).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to pick a smallish buffer size, and [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) the observations before plotting them.

The filter is very easy to implement, but requires calibration. For this application, I'd tune the parameters by hand until the level of smoothness of the resulting graph is pleasing to the eye.